# Get Id from post that I just created - Facebook Graph API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am creating some posts via Graph API but I need to get its ID to use it later.

This is the code I am using in PHP, can someone help me showing how to get the ID after creating the post?

I tried to do $response->id or $graphObject->id but it didn't work. Also, do I need to use this $graphObject in the last line of my code? I saw it somewhere else but i don't know what it does.

I did a print_r in the $graphObject and received this aswer:
Facebook\GraphObject Object ( [backingData:protected] => Array ( [id] => 741760479220480 ) )

Thanks

```
<?php


session_start();

require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookClientException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookPermissionException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookServerException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphUser.php' );



use Facebook\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookClientException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\FacebookPermissionException;
use Facebook\FacebookServerException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;
use Facebook\GraphUser;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('app','password');

$session = new FacebookSession('token');

$message = 'Test';
$link = "http://www.example.com.br";
$description = 'Description';
$name = 'Name';
$caption = 'Caption';

    $request = new FacebookRequest(
      $session,
      'POST',
      '/page_id/feed',
      array (
        'message' => $message,
        'link' => $link,
        'description' => $description,
        'published' => 'false',
        'name' => $name,
        'caption' => $caption,
        )
    );
    $response = $request->execute();
    $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject();

?>
```

Comment: What does `$graphObject` is giving to you?

Answer (score 0):

According to https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.0/user/feed/#publish it should be

```
$post_id = $graphObject->id;
```

Comment: I tried to do that, and when I did echo $post_id i got this error:

I tried to do that, and when I did echo $post_id i got this erros:

Answer (score 0):

Solve it!

```
 $post_id = $graphObject->getProperty('id');
```